# What's the difference between STDIN and tty at all?

Tags: perl, unix

Tt seems to be the same whether I read from `STDIN` and `/dev/tty`,

so what's the difference at all?

Answer (score 7):

`/dev/tty` is the controlling terminal for the current process. `STDIN` is the current input. If you redirect, e.g.,

```
perl script.pl <myfile.txt
```

`STDIN` will now come from `myfile.txt`, but `/dev/tty` would still come from the controlling terminal. It's all UNIX, not Perl, and there is much more to it than that, but that's the difference in a nutshell.

Comment: What's the point of `controlling terminal` if I redirect the current input to `myfile.txt`?

Comment: the controlling terminal can still generate SIGINT and SIGTSTP even if the stdin is being read from a file.

Comment: @Alnitak ,will the **corresponding** characters be  queued in `/dev/tty` if I press `ctrl-c`?

Comment: @new_perl: Say you want to read data from file, but also ask the user for password. Or you want to show a nice progress bar while writing to `>file`.